# Training motor skills for inexperienced athletes

Tags: training, coaching, quidditch

I captain a team made up of a group of players coming from very different backgrounds, something quite common in our sport. Some of them, all in their 20s, have no prior sports experience, and their main "physical" issue is that even if they have learnt some skills specific to our sport they lack overall coordination and dexterity, making them less adaptable on the pitch and slower learners in training.

What should I do to help them develop their motor skills and proprioception? Are there exercises I can teach them that they can replicate at home in their own time without needing complicated equipment?